# How to realise rows in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf

How can I force realisation of virtualised (and offscreen) rows in DataGrid?

Ideally I want to keep the rows virtualised by default and only realise them when I need to. Unfortunately this:

```
(DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(j);
```

returns `null` for virtualised rows and I don't see a way to change it.

Setting the row virtualisation to `false` does not force realisation of existing items, so switching it off doesn't do what I need.

Comment: UI containers are created once they are scrolled into view. You can/must do this manully. You wouldn't have this issue when you would use the controls correctly. You should create data models inside an ObservableCollection and then assign them to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` (or `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` in general), preferably via data binding. This way you don't have to care about item containers or scroll viewers. You simply access the data sorce collection and pick the items you need. When you are dealing with UI elelments in WPF in order to handle your data you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Usually your model is either a model class, where each instance represents a row and properties a cell. or you use the DataTable class, which makes handling database data a lot easier.

Comment: @BionicCode You're assuming too much about my situation. My use case here is "Create a snapshot of what the user sees in a generic way". The code here does not know anything about the underlaying data model and it needs to capture exactly what's displayed in a given DataGrid. I know how to do it via models if they're known, but in this case I know what I'm doing and the question is precisely "How do I realise a row so the formatted content can be captured".

Comment: The fact that I have to assume too much about your situation proofs the poor quality of your question. In your question there was never the talking about *"what the user sees"*. Only about UI virtualization. If it is about what the user sees then UI virtualization is not the topic as the user can only see realized items and everything visible (inside the viewport) is already realized.

Comment: You should definitely update your question and provide more details. What does snapshot mean, data, visual (image)? Data doesn't make sense as you said you know how to handle data models. Image daoesn't make sense too as you are handling UI containers.

Comment: Also what is `j`? Maybe your index is wrong? But enough guessing for me. You should know how to aks a question and what it takes to answer one (information).

Comment: It's already included in the question: "This should include the result of all the converters and current formatting, so using the underlaying item is not possible." The index is not wrong - I'm getting null result because the row is not realised yet. (again, included in the question) My question is exactly what you can see in the title and content (forcing realisation) - I'm providing more context about the use case as a response to the initial comment only - why I want to realise the rows is not really important.

Comment: Removed unnecessary / distracting context. The question is about row realisation.

Comment: The answer is still the same: 1) Generally, you have to scroll the not visible item into the view in order to force realization of the associated container 2) You didn't provide enough information to review your code. You say the index is correct, but maybe you are mistaken here? Maybe the problem is somewhere else - no code there to review 3) If you can see the row then it is realized. If you can't see the row, it is not. Talking about visible rows is equal to talking about realized rows (ignoring paging or cache here), that's why I'm concerned about the index

Comment: 4) Still don't know what kind of snapshot we are talking about: image, data, meta data? It's important because your approach could be generally wrong. My critique is not meant to harass you. It's simply to tell you that you are (still) missing crucial information.

Comment: Basically get the ScrollViewer and scroll to the item's index (in a virtualizing scenario where ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True").

Comment: What I do later really doesn't matter - the code already exists and works with row virtualisation turned off (which also confirms the indexes are not a problem). The only question is whether realisation of a given row can be triggered in code. Yes, it can be done with scrolling the row into the view and I'll be happy to upvote that answer. However, I'm after achieving that while keeping the items off-screen.

Comment: Sorry, but no. Turning off UI virtualization does not proof that your index is correct. When turned off, all containers are instantly generated on initialization or source collection modifcation. Of course, then every index within the bounds will return a container. Your are thinking worng as you don't seem to understand the fact that items must be generated to be visible, hence only visible items are generated. It''s very likely that your index tries to reference a container that is not visible and therfore not generated.

Comment: UI virtualization: the underlying Panel implements IScrollInfo and tracks scroll positions and maps them to an actual item index - that's why CanContentScroll must be true. If it detects that an index is being scrolled into the viewport, the Panel requests container generation/recycling - the virtual item is now realized. If you don't want to drill into the logic here and implement your own Panel or extend VirtualizingStackPanel in order to override virtual members you can only trigger realization by scrolling the required index into view, grab the generated container and scroll back.

Comment: Can't you just set EnableRowVirtualization false and refresh ?

Comment: This won't work. Also if it would, this will perform very bad as it theoretically would realize the complete Items collection at once (although you are only interested in a single or a few item(s). When you scroll manually you realize the N items depending of the viewport size only.

Comment: @Andy I should've thought of this - that's exactly what I wanted. Specifically: `dataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization = false; dataGrid.UpdateLayout(); value_getting_work...; dataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization = true;` works perfectly for my use case. Wanna submit the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy answered in the comments, refreshing the view would trigger the realisation.

Although it doesn't seem to be explicitly documented as doing so, `dataGrid.UpdateLayout()` after disabling the row virtualisation did the trick for all rows in the grid.

Since I wanted to access all the rows anyway, I ended up using:

```
dataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization = false;
dataGrid.UpdateLayout();
// get the content as displayed
dataGrid.EnableRowVirtualization = true;
```

This has the downside of realising rows at the same time, so you can't do batches and save the memory unfortunately. It also doesn't allow you to select the specific rows to realise.